# How to control network client pc

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, networking

In my  local network ,I have more than **10 pc**.I need to take care all of the pc.I want to know all pc’s hardware informations.I also want to control those pc,Suppose ,at this moment I want to **restart** one of my client pc.**Is it possible in C#**.if have any question plz ask.Thanks in advance
I use bellow syntax to execute command.

```
try
{
    // create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run,
    // and "/c " as the parameters.
    // Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows,
    // and then exit.
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = 
        new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + "shutdown /r /m \\172.16.1.3 /t 1 /");

    // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
    // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    // Do not create the black window.
    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
    proc.Start();

    // Get the output into a string
    string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    // Display the command output.
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
catch (Exception objException)
{
    // Log the exception
}
```

Using the above code I get the message **"The network path was not found."**

Comment: Couldn't you just use terminal services (remote desktop) or the windows command line?

Comment: using windows command how to restart client pc.will you plz show some syntax

Comment: Issue the following command: `shutdown /r /m \\COMPUTERNAME /t SECONDS /f`, where `\\COMPUTERNAME` is the name of the remote computer you want to shutdown, and `SECONDS` is the length of time in seconds you want to wait before the shutdown is initiated. (Edit: Also see [Wiki How-To](http://www.wikihow.com/Do-a-Remote-Shutdown-for-a-PC-on-a-LAN))

Comment: Why do programmers always want to rewrite things that already exist?  There are plenty of tools out there to do this job, pick one.  Also take a look at [not invented here syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Invented_Here).

Comment: But for someone, they will think that rewriting the things may explore their knowledge. I hope we all must encourage them all.

Comment: thanks for reply.Using this command i get "access is denied" message. shutdown /r /m \\COMPUTERNAME /t SECONDS /f .Here i set  COMPUTERNAME =ip of my client pc,SECONDS =time

Comment: Do you have the right privileges on the client PC - i.e. are you an Admin on that PC?

Comment: i have most of the pc's privilige but not all.I want to build up a system where i can control any task ,where privilige is not fact.

Answer (score 1):

Pls check the url.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317371

If you want to make a program which u can able to get the remote system information. You have to use Microsoft's `Remoting`.Here we can able to create an object in the remote system and we can able to control it.

It is possible to get System's information by executing the `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`.

It is possible to get system information using "systeminfo" .It is possible to take the output using C#

Pls chk the [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Execute_Command_in_CSharp.aspx).
I hope this will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a C# question, cause this can be done much more elegant with things like [Group Policy Editor](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307882/en-us), [System Management Server](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/configurationmanager/en/us/sms.aspx), [System Center Operations Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/operations-manager.aspx), etc.

To do some simple tasks on a remote machine you can take a look into the [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649).

Answer (score 0):

With those requirements my first stop would be [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There's for example the [Win32_OperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class with its `Reboot` and `Shutdown` methods and the [Win32_Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with all kinds of information about the CPU.

This MSDN section shows you how to use it from .Net: [Getting Started Accessing WMI Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186120.aspx)

This MSDN section has quite a lot of short VBScript samples for doing various things using WMI, and even if the code is different, at least you can see which WMI classes/methods/properties you should be looking at: [WMI Tasks for Scripts and Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394585%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Please note RB's comment though, you'll need to have the correct permissions for it to work.

Edit: Forgot that since you'll want to connect to other computers, this sample will be useful: [How To: Connect to a Remote Computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257337.aspx)